# Access button on popup window

Tags: jquery, .net

I have the following JQuery script within an aspx page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(".Test").click(function() {
alert("JQueryTest");
});
</script>
```

and a declaration for a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="TestButton" cssClass="Test" runat="server" Text="Test"  />
```

The button displays successfully on a pop-up window, however the JQuery script is not being executed when the button is clicked. I've tested this when the button has not been added to a popup window and the script is executed as expected (on click.) 
The popup window/control is of type AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender.

Does anyone have any reasons regarding why I can't access the button in this manner and has an alternative method of doing so?

Comment: What is it rendered as, is jQuery loaded?

Comment: jQuery is loaded by the master page, as I've said it seems to only be an issue accessing the button on a pop up window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include your event inside `document.ready()`

If you have the button into the opup you have to use `on()` because probably is created at runtime the button and there isn't instance of that inside the dom when starting the page.

Try this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.Test',function() {
     alert("JQueryTest");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: After trying this the script still does not seem to be executed.

Comment: Have you check if you have some error into your console? @DavieBrown

Comment: There aren't any errors reported in the console - If the button is not on this "pop up window" the script executes fine. There must be something I'm missing when accessing it in this manner.

Comment: If the "popup window" is really a popup window as in window.open, then of course you need to include jQuery in that window too

Comment: It now works as expected - Thanks. Would you care to add a little explanation if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you can also create a javascript function and assign it to your button's click event on a server side ussing the onclick attribute